# How to dynamically nest $or operator into $and Mongoose statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have 3 MongDB entries in a movie database:

```
"books": [
  {
    "_id": "xxxxxx",
    "title": "Fast Five",
    "rating": 6
  },
  {
    "_id": "yyyyyy",
    "title": "Kill Bill",
    "rating": 8
  },
  {
    "_id": "zzzzzzzz",
    "title": "Jumanji",
    "rating": 5
  }
]
```

I use GraphQL to retrieve the id of multiple movies if their title and rating match the criteria:

```
query{
   getMovies(itemFilterInput: {titles:["Fast Five", "Jumanji"], rating:6}){
    _id
   title
  }
}
```

This should return Fast Five.
I want this to translate into a mongoDB query like this:

```
{$and: [{rating:6}, {$or: [{title:"Fast Five", title:"Jumanji"}]}]}
```

In the backend, I use NodeJS and Mongoose to handle this query and I use something like this:

```
 getMovies: async args => {
try{
  let d = args.itemFilterInput;
  let filters = new Array();

  const keys = Object.keys(d);
  keys.forEach((key) => {
      // The titles case
      if(d[key] instanceof Array){
        var sObj = {};
        var sObjArray = [];
        d[key].map(prop => {
          sObj[key] = prop;
          sObjArray.push(sObj);
        });
        filters.push({$or: sObjArray});
      }else{
        // The rating case
        var obj = {};
        obj[key] = d[key];
        filters.push(obj);
      }
  });

  const items = await Item.find({$and: filters});
  return items.map(item => {
    return item;
  });
} catch (err) {
  throw err;
}
```

}

Unfortunately, this approach does not work.
What is the correct way to nest $or parameters in $and params?

Comment: Is [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SPFckWTX80j) what are you looking for?

Comment: It does the trick, thank you! The $or query worked as well if I just wrote it out, but I messed up somewhere with the object creation. Your solution is much cleaner and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

First of all, it is better to use the $in operator instead of a $and/$or combination.

And to solve the error: use quotes everywhere to declare the query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).